# How to combine all rows into one?

Tags: sql-server

For example, I have a table with below values:

```sql
DECLARE @TEMP TABLE (NUMBER INT);
DECLARE @TEXT VARCHAR(MAX)

INSERT @TEMP VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)

SELECT * FROM @TEMP
```

| NO |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |

What I want is

| NO |
| --- |
| 12345 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server)

Comment: Maybe, you should search "string concatenation". Like that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373100/t-sql-string-concatenation or like that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use MSSQL version later than 2013, you can do the following:

```
select STRING_AGG([NO],'') from @TEMP
```

Comment: `STRING_AGG` was added in SQL Server 2017, and there is no version 2013.

Answer (score 1):

if achieve the same using COALESCE function as well

```
DECLARE @TEMP TABLE (NUMBER INT);
DECLARE @TEXT VARCHAR(MAX)

INSERT @TEMP VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)


select @TEXT = COALESCE(@TEXT, '') + cast(NUMBER as nvarchar)
from @TEMP

select @TEXT
```